# How to change font color SecureField in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have custom Textfield.

```
CustomTextField(placeholder: Text("Login").foregroundColor(.white),
                                        text: $login)
                                        .background(Color(red: 0/255, green: 174/255, blue: 180/255))
                                        .opacity(0.5)
                                        .cornerRadius (29)
                                        .frame (height: 50)
                                        .font(.system(size: 40))
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
```

but i need create this for Securefield. How i can do this?
used form for custom Textfield

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
var placeholder: Text
@Binding var text: String
var editingChanged: (Bool)->() = { _ in }
var commit: ()->() = { }

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
        if text.isEmpty { placeholder }
        TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: editingChanged, onCommit: commit)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you mean this?

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @State var login : String = "aha"

    @State var password : String = "aha"

    var body : some View {

        CustomTextField(placeholder: Text("Login").foregroundColor(.white),
                        text: $login, password: $password)
            .background(Color(red: 0/255, green: 174/255, blue: 180/255))
            .opacity(0.5)
            .cornerRadius (29)
            .frame (height: 50)
            .font(.system(size: 40))
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: View {
    var placeholder: Text
    @Binding var text: String
    var editingChanged: (Bool)->() = { _ in }
    var commit: ()->() = { }
    @Binding var password : String

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if text.isEmpty { placeholder }
           // TextField("", text: $text, onEditingChanged: editingChanged, onCommit: commit)
            SecureField(text, text: $password) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```